# Ways to republish a paper in a different format

Tags: publications

Suppose I did publish an article under the CC 4.0. Now I would like to publish the paper again in my own classical two-column layout/format, because I am not happy with the single-column-layout of the publisher. This is actually bothering me a lot.

What are my options? I just know some keywords like "researchgate", "arXiv" etc. What are drawbacks of doing this (citations, indexvalues etc.)?

Comment: It may be annoying, but I would just let it go. It will be very confusing for future readers to see a paper which is (apparently) identical in content but different in formatting on arxiv, compared to the version they see in the journal. As a reader, I would be worried that there were other, non-obvious, changes.

Comment: And next time, publish in a journal which uses a two column format ;)

Comment: This sounds like it is not advised to republish to arXiv. I was thinking this is a good opportunity to get more attention for the article. If this also gives the opprtunity to reformat the text into a more professional layout, this would be perfect.

Comment: I'm not dissuading you from posting on arxiv -- all my papers go on there before they go to the journal. I then update the arxiv version to _exactly match_ the published version. I just think reformatting the paper according to your own preference is not a good idea and will be confusing.

Comment: Ok, now I understand you. But tables look horrible in the current layout, because they are streched over the whole page even if they just contain 2 or 3 columns. I think my own latex layout is easily more professional than this.